# glOrtho isn't changing coordinate system in 2D window?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

So unless I understood this wrong, in a default OpenGL window coordinates (0,0) are in the center of the screen.  I've set up the following resize function using `glOrtho`/`glViewport` to set the top left corner as (0,0).  But for some reason drawing a point at (0,0) still shows up at the center of the screen (and it's still on a -1/1 range).

Main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setTitle("OpenGL");
    w.resize(500,500);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
    format.setVersion(2,1);

    setFormat(format);
    context =new QOpenGLContext;
    context->setFormat(format);
    context->makeCurrent(this);

    openGLFuncions = context->functions();

}
void MainWindow::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0,w,h,0.0,-1.0,1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void MainWindow::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPointSize(10.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(0.5f,0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
```

MainWidow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QOpenGLWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void updateAnim();
protected:
    virtual void initilizeGL();
    virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    virtual void paintGL();
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
private:
    QOpenGLContext *context;
    QOpenGLFunctions *openGLFuncions;
};
```

Comment: You've implemented the `MainWindow::resizeEvent`. What do you do there? This function emits the resize event and triggers the call to `MainWindow::resizeGL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to do not any OpenGL call, except in `MainWindow::initilizeGL` and `MainWindow::paintGL`.

Add a state member (`_vp_valid`) to the class `MainWindow`, which indicates if the viewport and projection matrix was proper set and initialize it `false`:

```cpp
class MainWindow : public QOpenGLWindow
{

    // [...]

private:

   bool _vp_valid = false;

   // [...]
};
```

If the state is invalid, then update the viewport rectangle and set the projection matrix in `MainWindow::paintGL`:

```cpp
void MainWindow::paintGL()
{
    if ( !_vp_valid )
    {
        _vp_valid = true;
        int w = this->width();
        int h = this->height();

        glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0.0,w,h,0.0,-1.0,1.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPointSize(10.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(0.5f,0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
```

In `MainWindow::resizeGL` it is sufficient to invalidate the state:

```cpp
void MainWindow::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    _vp_valid = false;
}
```